# Чи можна скоротити слово «так» і казати просто «та» в тому ж значенні, як і «да»?

Tags: вибір-слова

Я ріс російськомовним і вже півтора роки вчу рідну мову. Питання для українців, які добре знають мову: чи можна скоротити слово «так» і казати просто «та» в тому ж значенні, як у слова «да»? Чув у багатьох відео/інтерв‘ю і навіть у польськомовному фільмі, але я не впевнений, чи так насправді, чи просто не чується мені літера к. Я розумію, що правильно казати «так», але мені цікаво, чи є такий варіант?

Comment: Коротка відповідь, яка не тягне на те, щоби називатися відповіддю на цьому форумі: так, у розмовній українській часто використовують "та" замість літнорми "так". UPD. Цю думку можна спокійно "красти".

Comment: @P.Vowk, будь ласка, не надавайте (напів-)відповідей у коментарях. Єдина мета коментарів — покращити допис, під яким їх надано. Окрім того, (напів-)відповіді у коментарях відлякують інших користувачів, які хотіли б відповісти, але соромляться «красти чужі думки».

Comment: @bytebuster дозволив красти в апдейті. Не погоджуюся, що не можна давати коментарі. Це просто думка, яка взагалі не тягне на відповідь, але людині це може бути важливо.

Comment: Уточніть, будь ласка, про значення "так" і "да". Вкажіть, будь ласка, приклади з цими словами. Бо є плутанина.

Comment: Наведіть, будь ласка, приклади, що Ви чули (у відео/інтерв‘ю і/або польськомовному фільмі), якщо можете.

Comment: Вибачте за пізню відповідь, ось інтерв'ю, де ви можете почути: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpYAJ1dF8E&t=1291s

наприклад 23:30

Валерій часто говорить так, можна почути в інших точках відео

Comment: @Andriy Ivanchenko Я запитую саме про випадки зі значенням згоди.

Comment: @Sasha Ще один приклад https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xIv6NCsEGBU&t=58s 7:05

Answer (score 3):

Зі [статті «Мовний булінг, або як повернутися до рідної» 
Юлії Капшученко](https://uain.press/blogs/movnyj-buling-abo-yak-povernutysya-do-ridnoyi-1130274):

> Скажімо, на Тернопільщині кажуть «та’» замість «так», на Львівщині взуття називають «мешти» та й слово «пательня» вперше я почула вже 19 років.

[P.Vovk](/u/240) у коментарі казав, що в розмовній українській часто використовують *та’* замість літературної норми *так*; я такого ніколи не помічав.

Складається враження, що це справді діалектне, тобто стосується певних регіонів.

Comment: Погоджуюся, що діалектне, властиве тернопільчанам, бо сам також ніколи не чув. Можливо, скорочене "так" в регіоні має походження з угорської або якихось балканських мов.

Answer (score 1):

Слово **«так»** — це службова частина мови, яка в реченні може виступати в ролі сполучника, частки або вигука в залежності від функції в контексті.

В запитанні йдеться про вживання слова **«так»** в ролі [модальної стверджувальної частки](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)) (*"так, згоден"*, *"так, добре"*).

**«Та»** — це підсилювально-видільна модальна частка ("*та не вже*?").

То ж відповідь: ***ні, не можна***.

Comment: Пане Sasha, я не така пихата жар-птиця, щоб до мене на ви,  та ще й з великої літери :)

Comment: Добре, буду на «ти» :). Усьо, тепер зрозумів, плюсанув. Але все-таки «В запитанні йдеться про вживання слова „так“» трішки збиває з пантелику, можна я заміню на «У запитанні йдеться про вживання слова „та“ замість слова „так“ саме в ролі модальної стверджувальної частки»?

Answer (score -1):

Як носій Української мови з центральної України - використання "та" в якості "так" ріже слух, хоча регіонально ніби пригадую щось таке. Проте "та" справді використовується у реченнях, де в російській мові використовується "да":

"Та се Лис!" - "Да это Лис". ~Фарбований Лис.

"Та тільки кохання не маєш" - "Да только не имеешь любви".

"Тупий та ще тупіший" - "Тупой да(и) ещё тупее" (назва фільму).

Comment: **Не погоджуюся**, що в цих випадках «та» має значення «так». По-моєму, у 1-х двох прикладах це типова підсилювальна частка (значення 3.1 [у СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ta)). Якби перед чим було запитання: «Чи це часом не лис?» — «Та', це лис» — то можна було б вважати, що тут «та'» у значенні «так», але я подивився контекст, там не передує питання, там навіть коми після «та» немає. Те саме в 2-му прикладі. У 3-му ж прикладі це типове єднальне «та» (замість «і» чи «але» — у цьому випадку замість «і»).

Comment: Ви дарма орієнтуєтеся на російську у цьому випадку. Річ у тім, що російське «да» поєднує в собі два кардинально різні значення: «да» у значенні згоди (укр. «так», англ. «yes») і «да» у значенні сполучника чи підсилювальної частки («мал, да удал», «да не скажи»; укр. «та»). Але автора цікавить саме можливість використання «та'» у значенні згоди («так», «yes»), а не в значенні сполучника чи підсилювальної частки.

Comment: Перепрошую, я зараз перечитав Вашу відповідь і побачив, що я, мабуть, спочатку неправильно Вас зрозумів. Ви ж і не казали, що «та» в цих прикладах має значення «так»/«yes», лише казали, що російською в таких випадках писали б «да». Тобто я фактичто 2-м коментарем повторив те саме, що й Ви (тільки іншими словами).